# Best way to store data for sending via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

What is the best way to store data which should be sent via Ajax using jQuery? I usually utilise:

1. A hidden `<input />` with my value to be sent:

   ```
   <input type='hidden' value='myValue'>
   ```
2. A link with a `data` attribut:

   ```
   <a href='apage.php' data-val='myValue'>
   ```

Note: I do not want to use plugins.

Comment: Code has to be indented with four spaces, `>` is for citations.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What format are you receiving the results of your Ajax request in, HTML code? There are other formats to send actual data, too, like JSON.

Comment: ah thanks Felix, I did not notice that.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Sending data via Ajax does not have to involve HTML at all. Where is the data coming from, which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Pekka, the sample one, without xml nor JSON, just values in $.post("page.php",{args},function(){})

Comment: @ Felix, data is within an input tag or a tag as I've show up.

Comment: I think you must understand the basics. How it's done. Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @Felix, I do not have any problem, I want just to know which is better, coz, I read that usind $("arg").data() is not recommended, is it?

Comment: @Kyle: But then it seems you question is not about *sending* data but which way is better to *store* data that should be sent.

Comment: @bluefoot, I did dude, Just question of performance if u want ^^

Comment: @Felix, maybe yes, my fault, so how to retrieve data from tags using jquery?

Comment: @Kyle: I edited your question. Please check it if it still expresses the issue you want to address.

Comment: then theoretically, sending with pure JS would be the best performance. But the development time will be bigger. So... I would just go with `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean which is better to store your data, the first way (input hidden with my value to be sent).

This is of course unless you're explicitly using HTML5, which isn't is recommended just yet. If you are, it's completely upto you, although the element metadata/html5 way is probably better!

But this doesn't seem to be anything to do with AJAX than just in-page data storage, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, u got it, then, I should take a look at metadata/html5, u know, I missed some basic notions, thanks rudi_visser.